# Check value of last 4 rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to check the value of the last `4` rows from DB. If these 4 rows have a specific value, Do something.

So the table looks like this:

```
______________
| id | value |
|____|_______|
| 1  |   a   |
|____|_______|
| 2  |   a   |
|____|_______|
| 3  |   a   |
|____|_______|
| 4  |   a   |
|____|_______|
| 5  |   a   |
|____|_______|
| 6  |   a   |
|____|_______|
```

Here is a fiddle to test with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1064b3/1

I can run the following query `SELECT * FROM testing ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4`, Then check with PHP:

```
//Count number of `a` from last 4 rows
$count = 0;

foreach($rows as $row){
    if($row['value'] == 'a'){
        $count++;
    }
}

//If last 4 rows value = 'a'
if($count == 4){
    //Do something 
}
```

Is there is a better way with SQL to get the rows only if the 4 rows value = `a` or return true or false maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(a.value)
 FROM(
      SELECT value
      FROM testing
      ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4
 ) AS a
 WHERE a.value = 'a'
```

If 3 is returned, it's TRUE (You have one not equal to A), FALSE otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it's working fine. But I'm trying to figure which answer is the best for speed and optimization?!

Comment: You can test it with sqlfiddle, it shows the time of execution

Comment: @mm1234 my one takes 5ms, second answer 8ms

Comment: I tested multiple times. But it's showing different execution time each time I run a query, Even the same query

Comment: It may be a different connection and connectivity stuff

Answer (score 1):

A multitude of ways, you could just use simple aggregation to count the rows:

```
select case when 
    count(case when value='a' then 1 end)=Count(*) 
  then 'true' else 'false' 
  end Last4AreA
from (
    select value
    from t
    order by id desc
    limit 4
)x
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it's working fine. But I'm trying to figure which answer is the best for speed and optimization?!

Comment: @Stu Change table name from `t` to `testing`